# No WiFi adapter found in Debian 12

Tags: linux, debian, wifi

I am trying to dual boot windows/linux (debian 12 bookworm) on my MSI Katana GF66 12UE laptop. I was able to install the operating system, but in the settings (in the WIFI section) it says no wifi adapter found. When using the [sudo lshw -c network] command:

```
*-network UNCLAIMED       
   description: Network controller
   product: Alder Lake-P PCH CNVi WiFi
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 14.3
   bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
   version: 01
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: iomemory:620-61f memory:6203134000-6203137fff
*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
   logical name: enp4s0
   version: 15
   serial: 04:7c:16:32:1c:f1
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=6.1.0-9-amd64 firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
   resources: irq:17 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:82104000-82104fff memory:82100000-82103fff
```

When using the lspci command:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 4621 (rev 02)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 12th Gen Core Processor 
PCI Express x16 Controller #1 (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Alder 
Lake-P Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0c)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Alder 
Lake Innovation Platform Framework Processor Participant (rev 02)
00:06.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 12th Gen Core Processor 
PCI Express x4 Controller #0 (rev 02)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation 12th Gen Core 
Processor Gaussian & Neural Accelerator (rev 02)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH USB 
3.2 xHCI Host Controller (rev 01)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH Shared 
SRAM (rev 01)
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P 
PCH CNVi WiFi (rev 01)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake 
PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 01)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake 
PCH HECI Controller (rev 01)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P SATA 
AHCI Controller (rev 01)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 51b8 (rev 01)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 51bd (rev 01)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH eSPI 
Controller (rev 01)
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Alder 
Lake PCH-P High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH-P SMBus Host 
Controller (rev 01)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P 
PCH SPI Controller (rev 01)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA106M 
[GeForce RTX 3060 Mobile / Max-Q] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GA106 High Definition 
Audio Controller (rev a1)
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co 
Ltd NVMe SSD Controller 980
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. 
RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
```

Are there any ideas where I should start and what should I do approximately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

recently I experienced something similar. In my case wifi was working during the install.
1st I added "contrib non-free-firmware" to all the existing lines in /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm main contrib non-free-firmware
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm main contrib non-free-firmware

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security main contrib non-free-firmware
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security main contrib non-free-firmware

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm-updates main contrib non-free-firmware
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bookworm-updates main contrib non-free-firmware
```

Then

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt reinstall firmware-iwlwifi
```

finally checked the /etc/network/interfaces file, during the installation I entered the SSID and WiFi password, all the lines of my Wifi adapter commented:

```
cat /etc/network/interfaces
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
#allow-hotplug wlo1
#iface wlo1 inet dhcp
    #wpa-ssid *********
    #wpa-psk  *********
```

hope it helps!

Update: code formatted.

Comment: Good answer but next time use syntax for formatting commands